# Python3.4 limiting floats to two decimal points

Tags: python-3.x

I am using python 3.4
and I want to limiting the a float number to two decimal points

```
round(1.2377, 2)
format(1.2377, '.2f')
```

These two would give my 1.24, but I don't want 1.24, I need 1.23, how do I do it?

Comment: I would look into the [`decimal` standard module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert to string and slice then convert to float :

```
>>> num=1.2377
>>> float(str(num)[:-2])
1.23
```

read more about [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)